# Replace values in dataframe based on rank

Tags: python

I have the 2 following dataframes:

Rank:

```
    A   B   C   D
0   85  88  44  80
1   22  34  80  92
2   80  80   2  31
```

and Value:

```
          a         b         c         d
0  0.671399  0.101208 -0.181532  0.241273
1  0.446172 -0.243316  0.051767  1.577318
2  0.614758  0.075793 -0.451460 -0.012493
```

In table "Value" I would like to replace all values for which rank is > 80 with the value that has rank = 80 (by column)

So far I have an iterative process that takes way too long and there surely is a pythonic way to do it with a mapping but I can't figure out the syntax.
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since the indexs match you can use .loc[] to set the value, a for loop can be used to do this for all columns

```
for column in value.columns:
    value.loc[rank[column.upper()] > 80, column] = (
        value.loc[list(rank[column.upper()]).index(80), column])
```

output:

```
      a         b         c         d
0  0.614758  0.075793 -0.181532  0.241273
1  0.446172 -0.243316  0.051767  0.241273
2  0.614758  0.075793 -0.451460 -0.012493
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) function for conditional replacing

```
(value.rename(columns=str.upper) # match column names with 'rank'
      .where(rank <= 80, lambda x: x[rank == 80].max(), axis=1))
```

Output

```
          A         B         C         D
0  0.614758  0.075793 -0.181532  0.241273
1  0.446172 -0.243316  0.051767  0.241273
2  0.614758  0.075793 -0.451460 -0.012493
```